# Why am I not able to convert a string variable to an integer value?

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting unexpected results while doing string manipulation and conversion to integer value. Please someone help me interpret why I am getting these results. I will show my code and print results and explain what I expect instead.

```
var startIndex = string?.index((string?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 10)  
var endIndex = string?.index(of: ".")!  
var field = String(describing: string?[startIndex!..<endIndex!])  
print(field as Any)
```

Prints:

```
Optional("10")
```

Just what I expected.

```
print(field.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8))
```

Prints:

```
14
```

Not what I expected. I expected a value of 2 since "10" is only 2 characters long.

```
print(Int(field) as Any)
```

Prints:

```
nil
```

Not what I expected. I expected a value of 10, since a string of "10" converted to integer would be an integer value of 10.

I just duplicated this code in Playground and it works as expected. I don't know why.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

var string = "Network\t\t\t10.0.0.0/8\nClass\t\t\t\tA\nRequired Hosts:\n2\n\nRequired hosts\t2\nAvailable hosts\t2\nSubnet\t\t\t\t10.0.0.0/30\nRange start\t\t10.0.0.1\nRange end\t\t\t10.0.0.2\nBroadcast\t\t\t10.0.0.3\nMask\t\t\t\t255.255.255.252\n\n"

print(string)

var startIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 10)

var endIndex = string.index(of: ".")!

var field = String(describing: string[startIndex..<endIndex])

print(field as Any)
print(field.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8))
print(Int(field) as Any)
```

Prints:

```
Network            10.0.0.0/8
Class                A
Required Hosts:
2

Required hosts    2
Available hosts    2
Subnet                10.0.0.0/30
Range start        10.0.0.1
Range end            10.0.0.2
Broadcast            10.0.0.3
Mask                255.255.255.252


10
2
Optional(10)
```

Comment: I think you do this: print(Int(Optional("10")) as Any). You should write this: print(Int(field!))

Comment: You are using too many confusing question and exclamation marks

Comment: `String(describing:)` is almost *never* what you should use.

Comment: The point I'm trying to solve is that I need to convert the string "10" to an integer value. Instead I am getting a nil value. That is causing an error in my code. My app will not function as it should as long as I can't convert that string to an integer. I am adding to my question the addition that I am able to get the code to work in Playground. I think there is a problem with the source of the string variable.

Comment: Please add an example string and the expected result.

Comment: @vadian Yes. I included the exact string in the playground code as in the first set of code. The expected result has to do with the simple value of ten as an integer value. That's all I'm working on right now is making sure I can at least convert that string value of "10" to an integer. I don't know what happened. This code worked before. It might have something to do with data corruption because I didn't properly conform the file to NSFilePresenter to use the file with iCloud.

Comment: Your playground code did what I suggested in my answer: remove the optionality.

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope this will help:

```
var field = String("10")  
var intValue = Int(field)
print(intValue!)
```

Result: **10**

Comment: An answer is more helpful if it *explains* the problem and the solution. – And don't teach forced unwrapping to a Swift beginner!

Answer (score 0):

> var field = String(describing: string?[startIndex!..

field now has the value `Optional("10")`.

> print(field.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8))

prints 14 because that's the length of the string `Optional("10")`. No surprise here.

> print(Int(field) as Any)

is nil because the String `Optional("10")` is not convertible to Int.

If you remove the optionality from `string`, everything works just fine:

```
if let str = string {
    var startIndex = str.index((string?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 10)
    var endIndex = str.index(of: ".")!
    var field = String(describing: str[startIndex..<endIndex])
    print(field)

    print(field.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8))

    print(Int(field))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the code is a bit cumbersome it should work if the first digit is the 11th character in the string

However in this case `Scanner` is much more reliable because the *offset* can be dynamic and the result is `Int`.

The scanner scans up to the first decimal digit and then it scans an `Int` and assign it to the `result` variable.

```
let string = "Network\t\t\t10.0.0.0/8\nClass\t\t\t\tA\nRequired Hosts:\n2\n\nRequired hosts\t2\nAvailable hosts\t2\nSubnet\t\t\t\t10.0.0.0/30\nRange start\t\t10.0.0.1\nRange end\t\t\t10.0.0.2\nBroadcast\t\t\t10.0.0.3\nMask\t\t\t\t255.255.255.252\n\n"

var result = 0
let scanner = Scanner(string: string)
scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: .decimalDigits, into: nil)
scanner.scanInt(&result)
print(result) // 10
```

Comment: OK. Thank you. I think I will do that. That seems a much better way of doing the code.